# Format Date for Manual Insertion into post

Tags: date, date-time

I have the following `$mydate = "26 January, 2012, 5:05 AM";`

I want to format this date properly so I can insert it into a post_date. Is there a simple way to do it?

```
$post_ information = array (
    //other data is also inserted
    'post_date' => $mydate;
);
```

Comment: `strtotime` would be your best bet but it doesn't work. Where did you get that date string?

Comment: If you can back up a step or two it might be easier. If not, you probably have to parse that string with regex.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I got this from an RSS feed that I am reading. I am basically trying to import the data into a post. Everything works fine except that I can't get the date to format properly.

Comment: In mysql, the accepted date format is Y-m-d H:i:s, u can customized the display of post date in post loop

Comment: @TamilSelvan I understand about the formatting being Y-m-d H:i:s but... the issue is how do we get "26 January, 2012, 5:05 AM"; to look like Y-m-d H:i:s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That format is almost readable by `strtotime`. Remove the commas and it will convert.

```
$t = '27 January, 2012, 5:05 AM';
$t = str_replace(',','',$t);
$t = strtotime($t);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$t);
```